# Finite lines on hypersurfaces always in symmetric position?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb {P}^n _\mathbb {C}$ be a general hypersurface of degree $d$, such that $2(n-1)=d+1$. It would be easy to see that $X$ contains finitely many projective lines. I have a series of questions on the symmetry of these lines:

1. If we take $X'$ to be the Fermat hypersurface (namely, defined by $x_0^d+x_1^d+\cdots$), is it true that these lines are symmetric? That is to say, the automorphism group acts transitively on these lines.
2. For a general $X$ and any two lines $l_1,l_2$ on it, is it true that we can deform it to some $X'$ such that there exists some automorphism of $X'$ which maps $l_1$ to $l_2$?
3. For a general $X$, is it true that any two lines $l_1,l_2$ are homological equivalent?

Apparently, 1 implies 2 (take $X'$ in 2 to be the $X'$ in 1), and 3 looks even weaker. However, I have no idea how to prove or disprove the statement 1. Any comments would be helpful!

Comment: Starting from $n=4$ (quintic threefold), the Fermat hypersurface will have a continuous family of lines, but its degree is high enough so that its automorphism group is finite, so 1 is not true in general (For Fermat cubic surface, the claim is probably true, though.) 3 is true by Lefschetz hyperplane theorem.

Comment: @AGlearner Thank you for your comment. Maybe I should replace the Fermat hypersurface by a general one in the statement of 1, as you pointed out. Besides, could you explain why statement 3 follows from the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem? I did not see that.

Comment: A general hypersurface should have trivial automorphism group. Lefschetz hyperplane theorem imples $H_2(X)=H_2(\mathbb P^n)=\mathbb Z$, the image of a line $l\subseteq X$ in $\mathbb P^2$ is clearly the generator $1\in \mathbb Z$, so any two lines are homologous.

Comment: @AGlearner Sorry, it should be: if there exists some special $X'$ such that its automorphism group acts transitively on the lines. And for 3: yes, it is quite clear. Thank you!